# Unable to import in python i am new in coding pls help :)

Tags: python

I am new to coding and I wanted to look for some beginner friendly projects so I found this:

[Tutorial source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J_qcttfnJA&t=446s)

So I wanted to import this right here

[image: (picture)]

and this is the error

[image: error]

It would be nice if somebody could help me out.

Comment: Did you use pip to install these modules?

Comment: yes I used pip for those which weren't installed yet. But the Google api things were already installed with python

Comment: sorry if I my English is a bit trash but I am from Germany and I am only 14 Years so my English isn't that good

Comment: You should follow more beginner friendly tutorials. She is using `virtualenv` for development purposes. If you even used pip it should be globally install the packages but if you are following tutorial she probably install packages in an `virtualenv`.

Comment: ok thanks for replying could you give me some tips how I could learn python ?

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text (not image) in question (not comment)

Comment: BTW: your image shows only warnings which have nothing to do with errors when you run code. Did you run it ?

Comment: k it's my first post here sorry

Comment: yeah I tried but it hadn't worked I'll try again tomorrow

Comment: when you run code then you can get errors which start with word `Traceback` - and these errors are important. Warnings are not so important.

Comment: ok thanks as I already said I am a really hard beginner :) thanks for your help